# Cartesian to polar coordinates, complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

If $$z=re^{i\theta}$$ write $$f(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}$$ as $$f(z)=u(r,\theta)+iv(r,\theta)$$What i did is $$z=re^{i\theta}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)\space and\space f(z)=z+z^{-1}\space so$$
$$f(z)=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)+\frac{r(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)}{r²(\cos²\theta+\sin²\theta)}=r³(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)+r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$
$$=r³\cos\theta+r\sin\theta+ir³\sin\theta+ir\sin\theta=r\cos\theta(r²+1)+ir\sin\theta(r²+1)$$

It makes sense that?

Comment: what is sen? Do you mean sin?

Comment: yes is sin, sorry.

Comment: Also, use `\sin` and `\cos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly noted:
$$\dfrac{1}{z}=z^{-1}$$
And with $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$, we have:
$$z^{-1}=r^{-1}(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^{-1}$$
Now, use De Moivre's formula to write:
$$z^{-1}=r^{-1}\big(\cos{(-\theta)}+i\sin{(-\theta)}\big)$$
Now, we have:
$$z+z^{-1}=r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta+r^{-1}\cos\theta-ir^{-1}\sin\theta$$
$$f(z)=\cos\theta(r+r^{-1})+i\sin\theta(r-r^{-1})$$
$$f(z)=u(r,\theta)+iv(r,\theta)$$
with:
$$u(r,\theta)=\cos\theta(r+r^{-1})$$
and: 
$$v(r,\theta)=\sin\theta(r-r^{-1})$$

Comment: what I did is wrong?

Comment: Yes, let me elaborate.